# Hotspot connection lost to PC every few minutes

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, windows, data-connection

My only internet connection at present is via a hotspot on Moto G7 (running Android Version 10) connecting via GiffGaff (which runs on the O2 network). I keep the phone data on 3G as 4G seems slower when the network strength is low.

I have had a connectivity problem between my phone and my Asus laptop running Win 10 Home (build 19042.1348) for about the last year.

Sometimes the connection is fine running at 1-3 Mbps download but frequently it disconnects. I can often get a reconnection by disconnecting and reconnecting my connection to the phone hotspot on my laptop and/or by running Windows' network Troubleshooter. This disconnection happens every 3-10 minutes so having to reconnect 10 times an hour is not unusual.

I would be grateful for two things:
Firstly if there is an obvious solution I would love to hear it;
Secondly I am unfamiliar with this area and would be grateful for a recommendation of diagnostic tools.

I emphasise this is a problem of connectivity between the laptop and the phone via wifi. This is not a problem of the network to the phone.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I actually have the same problem on a phone (samsung grand prime +) that i am using to wifi hotspot my to simcardless tablet. The wifi hotspot keeps on disconnecting periodically after about 5 minutes. What I do is that every time I reboot the phone, firstly i switch on wifi, then switch on mobile hotspot and then switch off mobile hotspot and then switch on mobile hotspot again. Turns out that this simple procedure solves everything and there are no more disconnections. Try it and maybe it will work for you too.

Comment: Yep I have had some success with rebooting phone and PC but does not always work but sometimes cures it for quite a while. When you say you "switch on wifi" do you mean on the computer? Anyway I'll give it a go as have not rebooted for about 5 hours.

Comment: Sadly worked for 1 min 58 seconds :-(

Comment: @BeNice I meant that switch on wifi first then switch on mobile hotspot on the phone that you are using to hotspot to the pc.

Comment: I am actually using my phone now which has the same problem but it has been on for an hour.

Comment: After switching on phone (1)switch on wifi (2) switch on mobile hotspot (3) switch off mobile hotspot (4) switch on mobile hotspot amd you are good to go----   [After doing all this im certain that it will not switch off again. You may want to do this every time you switch off your phone

Comment: It does not work for me. (Just checking you do mean switch on the wifi on the computer. Just wondered if you meant data on the phone... In any case not working here sadly.)

Comment: I dont think you are getting me. Maybe my english is bad. After rebooting your Moto G7 switch on wifi (on your Moto G7 not on your pc), on your Moto G7 switch on mobile hotspot, on your Moto G7 switch off mobile hotspot, then lastly switcb it on mobile hotspot again amd you are good to go.

Comment: @Silent thanks - it was a language thing. You mean switch off the data on the phone etc. (The wifi (IEEE 802.11 stuff) is only between the phone and the computer.) I had tried switching data on and off in many ways already. As it happens I have found a robust solution for my situation but thanks for trying. I'll post the answer in a day or so. Thanks Steve

Comment: @BeNice  Oh you have found a solution am glad you found one. I thought we had the same problem but turns out its not so. So the problem is between your phone and computer but for me its global whether the client is a phone or pc it will always disconnect. Not exacty disconnect but the phone will stop broadcasting the wifi network and at the same time the wifi hotspot notification would still be on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my Redmi Note 4 (mido). In my case, the hotspot turned off automatically after 3-5 minutes of use. I was running a custom ROM (Lineage OS 17 - Android 11). This was easily fixed by flashing a new kernel (suggested by the developer of the RO himself).
However, if you are not familiar with terms such as TWRP or fastboot, you should wait for the next software update or keep looking for some other ways people might have fixed this error.

Meanwhile, you could use USB Tethering to solve your issue. You can use the internet on your PC with 3 simple steps.

1. Connect your phone to your PC.
2. Open Settings on your phone.
3. Tap Network & internet > Hotspot & Tethering, then tap the switch to turn USB tethering on.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and finally got it fixed! Please change the password encryption to WPA2/WPA3 Personal or WPA3. My Android access point had WPA2 Wi-Fi encryption enabled and my laptop was dropping the connection every 2 minutes. Now it works perfectly.